# Django Class Based View Form Won't Save Data To Database

Tags: python, database, django, forms

I can not get my form data to commit to my sqlite3 database. I don't see any errors. I can commit data through admin, but not through my own controller using form. I've tried many diff. combos and still no success. I would like to use class based view, please. Everything works, the form just won't save the data to database. There are no errors.

url: `url(r'^create/$', CreateRequest.as_view())`

forms.py:

```
class CreateForm(ModelForm):
    date_due = forms.DateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)
    class Meta:
        model = Request
        fields = ['region', 'user_assigned', 'user_requester',  'description']
```

views.py:

```
class CreateRequest(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Request
    fields = ['region', 'user_assigned', 'user_requester', 'date_due', 'description']
    template_name = "requests_app/createRequest.html"
    form_class = CreateForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        objects = form.save()
        return super(CreateRequest, self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_assigned = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_assigned')
    user_requester = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_requester')
    date_due = models.DateTimeField()
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    objects = models.Manager()
    open_requests = OpenRequests()
    completed_requests = CompletedRequests()

    def mark_completed(self):
        if not self.completed:
            self.completed = True
            self.date_completed = datetime.datetime.now()
```

index.html:

```
<h1>hi</h1>
<form action="/create/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.region.errors }}
        <label for="id_region">Region</label>
        {{ form.region }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.user_assigned.errors }}
        <label for="id_user_assigned">User Assigned</label>
        {{ form.user_assigned }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.user_requester.errors }}
        <label for="id_user_requester">user_requester: </label>
        {{ form.user_requester }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <p> {{ form.date_due.errors.as_text }} </p>
        <label for="id_date_due">Due Date</label>
        {{ form.date_due }}
    </div>
     <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.description.errors }}
        <label for="id_description">Descr.</label>
        {{ form.description }}
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Request" /></p>
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for err in form%}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
          <p class="form-error">{{ err }}</p>
          <p class="form-error">{{ err.label_tag }} {{ field }}</p>
      </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It might be this: you have omitted the required `date_due` field from your `CreateForm` class. The `fields` attribute of your `CreateRequest` view is ignored when supplying your own form class

Comment: That was a good try, but didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Override form_invalid and make sure there aren't any form.errors

Answer (score 1):

in views.py you don't need this line: objects = form.save()
It can be

```
class ContaktCreateView(CreateView):

model = Contakt
form_class = ContaktForm
template_name = "www/www_contakt.html"
success_url = '/thanks/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    return super(ContaktCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also I'm not using action in form action="/create/" method="post"

You are calling this html form via your line in urls.py:

```
url(r'^create/$', CreateRequest.as_view())
```

which is using your CreateRequest view which is using your index.html form file.